# Prorate a monthly charge to daily for a partial month

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, formula

I'm using SQL Server and SSRS. I have a table with a monthly charge for a service. I need to be able to calculate what the charge is for a partial month. I need the monthly charge prorated to a daily charge, but I can't just divide by 30. I need it depending on what month I am looking at. 31 for months with 31 days, 28 for February, etc.

Can I do this in SQL?

Comment: Yes you can this in sql. I suspect however you desire more of an answer. For that to happen you need to provide more of a question. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: use the eomonth function or get the last date then pro-rate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the total number of days for current month by:

```
 SELECT DAY(EOMONTH(DateColumn))
 FROM TABLE
```

And in your case, I am guessing the query should look like:

```
 SELECT TotalCharges * 1.0/DAY(EOMONTH(DateColumn))
 FROM TABLE
```

Comment: Thank you so much! EOMONTH is a new one for me!  That is awesome.